# undefined method `each_with_index' for 0:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
NoMethodError in Habits#new
where line #29 raised:
<% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
```

How can we remove this error?

The idea is that Users commit to certain days to do their positive habits, but if they miss a day, they have to check it off in the form. Everyday they miss is a day they have to make up for before advancing to the next level.

**habits/_form**

```
    <% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
  <p>
    <label> Level <%= index + 1 %>: </label>
    <%= f.check_box :missed_one, checked: (level.missed_days > 0) %>
    <%= f.check_box :missed_two, checked: (level.missed_days > 1) %>
    <%= f.check_box :missed_three, checked: (level.missed_days > 2) %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**habits.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
has_many :levels
serialize :committed, Array
validates :date_started, presence: true
before_save :set_level
acts_as_taggable
scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

def save_with_levels
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.save
end

def self.comitted_for_today
today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
where(id: ids)
end 

def levels
        return 0 unless date_started #This is the real cause of error, but I need this line to prevent .to_date error from being nil
        committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
        n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }
        actual_days = n_days - self.missed_days

  case n_days     
      when 0..9
        1
      when 10..24
        2
      when 25..44
        3
      when 45..69
        4
      when 70..99
        5
      else
        "Mastery"
    end
end

private
  def set_level
    self.level = levels
  end   
end
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to load the `new` template you are getting this error because `@habit.levels` is returning `0` rather than an enumerable object. Since you can't iterate over a `Fixnum`, the exception is being thrown when it gets to the `.each_with_index` call. Check out this line in your code:

```
def levels
  return 0 unless date_started
  ...
end
```

It looks like you're validating the presence of `date_started` but with this `@habit` the `#levels` method is returning `0`.

As ilan berci points out, this line is always going to fail when chained with `.each_with_index` because it is named `levels` but returns a `Fixnum`. Looking back at the top of your model, however, you've already declared `has many :levels` up there, which generates its own `levels` method that will gather all the levels associated with the given `@habit` and return them as an enumerable object .

It sounds like that's what you were expecting to happen based on the use of `each_with_index`, but when you declared the other `levels` method further down in the model, it overrides the method given to you by the `has_many :levels` line. If you really do need to iterate over a collection of a habit's levels, you should change the name of the custom `levels` method that is now designed to return a `Fixnum` based on the value of `n_days`.

Comment: Is there a way to include that line while fixing this error because I need that line?

Comment: what's the actual value of this habit's `date_started` in the database?

Comment: datetime is the value. Levels figures out what level a User is on based upon what days a User committed to and what day he started.

Comment: Maybe if you renamed your "def levels" to "def currentLevel", and adjusted its usages you could avoid the naming collision, and also avoid potential confusion that "def levels" returns in fact a single value, not multiple levels, and that single value is sometimes a number, sometimes a string.

Comment: @railsdog is absolutely right. I updated my answer based on that and ilan berci's note about the conflict between `has_many :levels` and `def levels` further down.

Answer (score 2):

Class `Habit` is declaring that it has many levels which to rails, means you have a class Level somewhere that has a foreign key to `Habit`.  If this isn't the case, then remove: `has_many :levels`.  If it indeeds the case however, then you are overriding it further down in your code with `def levels`

Your `def levels()` override is returning a `Fixnum` which can't be enumerated.